# Получение JSON в IE9 с XMLHttpRequest и асинхронность

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, es5

Нужно добыть `json` с сервера и записать в переменную для дальнейшего использования. Чистый `js` - `es5`, без доп. библиотек и т.п. **IE9**.

```
var aJson = null;

    var req = new (("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest);

    req.open('GET', '/j/j.json', true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            jJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText) // как в ie9 сделать асинхронно?
        else {
            console.log(this.status || this.statusText);
            return
        }
    }
    req.send();

document.write(jJson) // дает null
```

Comment: без es6 только вглубь идти в коллбеки

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev а не подскажете кодом как?